# Crossing the Chinese border with a 50cc bike

Tags: china, borders, automobiles, bicycles, motorcycles

I am planning to travel around in Asia a bit with my 50cc Simson, Ive heard that it is quiet a trouble to bring a car/motorcycle into China and it costs a lot of money and there is a lot of paperwork need. So actually I have heard from a lot of countries in Asia (for example Iran, Turkmenistan and Vietnam) that motorbikes (A moped like an old German Simson) below 50cc is mostly considered a bicycle. So it's pretty easy to cross the border, there is almost no paperwork, no driver licence need and no money to pay to the Government. So yeah maybe somebody knows if that's the same for China?

Comment: I wouldn’t count on entering China as a foreigner prior to 2023 at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I first joined this site in 2011, on a trip from London to Mongolia overland.  A friend was travelling at the same time on a Honda Cub (90cc?) on a similar route, with the intention of reaching Beijing.

He tried everything, but the rules were he would have to pay for an escort while he travelled through the country.  And somehow get rid of the bike at the end.

Eventually, it was simpler to dispose of the bike in Ulan Bator, in Mongolia through the charity [Mongol Rally](https://www.theadventurists.com/adventures/mongol-rally/), and fly on to Beijing.